# How to change NSProgressIndicator color from gray to white?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, colors, nsprogressindicator

The default color for NSProgressIndicator is gray but I want it to be white.

Is there anyone who knows how to do it ? Please let me know.

Many thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot change it directly but there are several open source alternative implementations you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Create subclass of NSProgressIndicator inside method do like this

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // Drawing code here.
        [self setControlTint:NSGraphiteControlTint];
    CGContextSetBlendMode((CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort], kCGBlendModeSoftLight);
    [[[NSColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:dirtyRect];
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

Comment: For me this just drew a coloured square around the progress indicator, not actually changing the indicators colour: http://i.imgur.com/J3VqaxY.png

Comment: not working on 10.10+